# ng-cloak is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written a code that takes some text input and removes the '#' tags in the text.The code is running fine. But initially when the page loads i am getting '{{textWithHashes | textWithoutDashes}}'.This is not very appealing.I have tried using ng-cloak but still I am not able to hide it. Can someone please tell me why it is not working and if there is better ways to hide it.

Html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Removing the delimiters from the Text</title>
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/appModule1.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="appModule" ng-controller="appModuleCtrl">

        <input type="text" ng-model="textWithHashes">

        <!--The next line will give the text without the hash tags-->

        <label ng-cloak>{{textWithHashes | textWithoutDashes}}</label>

    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript file:

```
var appModule=angular.module('appModule',[]);

appModule.filter('textWithoutDashes',function(){
    return function(text){
        return text.split('#').join(' ');
    }
});


appModule.controller('appModuleCtrl',function(){

});
```

Comment: try this,class="ng-cloak"

Comment: @saikumar..that works!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-bind` and filter the text in your controller (this is recommanded performance wize as well):

`<label ng-bind="textWithHashes"></label>`

And in your controller:

```
appModule.controller('appModuleCtrl',function($scope, $filter){
    $filter('textWithoutDashes')($scope.textWithHashes);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to ng-cloak documentation ( https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak ) you must add this css in head tag:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```